# Connecting tape drive to RAID controller

Tags: raid, sas

I'm trying to install a Quantum TC-L52AN tape drive in my workstation. The attached IBM ServeRAID M1115 SAS/SATA controller has two SFF-8087 jacks, one of which is connected to four hard drives in RAID 10. The controller can have drives connected to it that operate independently, which means I shouldn't have to reconfigure the existing RAID array.

Can I connect the tape drive to the unused jack or do I need to install a dedicated controller?

Comment: Have you just tried connecting it?

Comment: I have the choice of buying a standard cable (in the case I need to use a dedicated controller) or a split cable (in the case I can connect it to the existing controller). I'd like to avoid spending money on the more-expensive split cable if I end up needing a separate controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect it without issues.  As long as you dont attempt to put it in an array (which it most likely wouldnt let you), it should work fine.